# Performance issue with reading tiff image in C# in windows 2012 r2 server

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, tiff

We have a .NET application that reads the tiff files and displays it in the UI. We recently upgraded our servers from win 2008 to win 2012 r2 and started seeing serious performance issue with our application. We analyzed our code and found the following code execution to be comparatively slow in win 2012 R2 server compared to win 2008 server. We have .net framework 4.6 installed in both the machines.

Bitmap.Save(byteStream_ImageFormat.Png)

Bitmap.Save(byteStream_oImgFile.RawFormat)

Bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page_page)

new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImageFormat.Png)

new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageFromFile.RawFormat)

I have attached the full project as well as sample image along with this post (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N8JK6lePqrRu_MiqFaYhoR5uwBrGDvU1/view).

The sample image is small but in our real application the sample image is larger than this. Please find the comparison summary below:

Our application performs 2-3 times slower in windows 2012 r2 machine than compared to windows 2008 machine when dealing with the tiff images.

```
     using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace ImageViewerTest

    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {


    private string[] files;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void runButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageFilePath.Text) || 
                    (!imageFilePath.Text.StartsWith("Multiple") && !File.Exists(imageFilePath.Text)))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Missing file name or file doesn't exist");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!imageFilePath.Text.StartsWith("Multiple"))
                    {
                        files = new string[] { imageFilePath.Text };
                    }

                    var logFile = Path.Combine(
                       Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                            "ImageViewerTestLog.csv");

                    // Truncate the file
                    File.WriteAllText(logFile, "");
                    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
                    var separator = ",";
                    results.Append("\"File Name\"" + separator + "Page" + separator + "Date" + separator + "API Call" + separator + "Time Elapsed (ms)" + separator + "Image Format" + Environment.NewLine);
                    var timestamp = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss";
                    foreach (string filePath in files)
                    {
                        var imageFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
                        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                        stopWatch.Reset();
                        stopWatch.Start();
                        Bitmap imageFromFile = new Bitmap(filePath);
                        stopWatch.Stop();
                        int count = imageFromFile.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
                        var fileName = "\"" + imageFile.Name + "\"";
                        results.Append(fileName + separator + (count) + separator + DateTime.Now.ToString(timestamp) + separator +
                                "new Bitmap(filePath)" + separator +
                                stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + separator + "NA" + Environment.NewLine);


                        for (int page = 0; page < count; page++)
                        {
                            // Measure Bitmap.SelectActiveFrame
                            stopWatch.Reset();
                            stopWatch.Start();
                            imageFromFile.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, page);
                            stopWatch.Stop();
                            results.Append(fileName + separator + (page + 1) + separator + DateTime.Now.ToString(timestamp) + separator +
                                "Bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page_page) " + separator +
                                stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + separator + "NA" + Environment.NewLine);

                            // Measure Bitmap.Save using Png
                            var byteStreamPNG = new MemoryStream();
                            stopWatch.Reset();
                            stopWatch.Start();
                            imageFromFile.Save(byteStreamPNG, ImageFormat.Png);
                            stopWatch.Stop();
                            results.Append(fileName + separator + (page + 1) + separator + DateTime.Now.ToString(timestamp) + separator +
                                "Bitmap.Save(byteStream_ImageFormat.Png)" + separator +
                                stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + separator + ImageFormat.Png.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

                            // Measure Bitmap.Save using original format
                            var byteStreamRawFormat = new MemoryStream();
                            stopWatch.Reset();
                            stopWatch.Start();
                            imageFromFile.Save(byteStreamRawFormat, imageFromFile.RawFormat);
                            stopWatch.Stop();
                            results.Append(fileName + separator + (page + 1) + separator + DateTime.Now.ToString(timestamp) + separator +
                                "Bitmap.Save(byteStream_oImgFile.RawFormat)" + separator +
                                stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + separator + imageFromFile.RawFormat.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

                            // Measure new System.Drawing.Bitmap using Png
                            stopWatch.Reset();
                            stopWatch.Start();
                            var imagePNG = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(byteStreamPNG);
                            stopWatch.Stop();
                            results.Append(fileName + separator + (page + 1) + separator + DateTime.Now.ToString(timestamp) + separator +
                                "new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImageFormat.Png)" + separator +
                                stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + separator + ImageFormat.Png.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                            imagePNG.Dispose();

                            // Measure new System.Drawing.Bitmap using original format
                            stopWatch.Reset();
                            stopWatch.Start();
                            var imageRawFormat = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(byteStreamRawFormat);

                            stopWatch.Stop();
                            results.Append(fileName + separator + (page + 1) + separator + DateTime.Now.ToString(timestamp) + separator +
                                "new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageFromFile.RawFormat)" + separator +
                                stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + separator + imageFromFile.RawFormat.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                            imageRawFormat.Dispose();
                            byteStreamRawFormat.Dispose();
                        }

                        File.AppendAllText(logFile, results.ToString());
                        results.Clear();
                        imageFromFile.Dispose();

                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
                var logFile = Path.Combine(
                       Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                            "Error.txt");
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString(), "Excetion:");
                File.WriteAllText(logFile, st.ToString()+"\n"+ex);
            }
        }

        private void fileExplorerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imageFilePath.Text = this.BrowseFile();
        }
        string BrowseFile()
        {
            try
            {
                dlgopenImageFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.TIF;*.TIFF;*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.TIF;*.TIFF;*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                dlgopenImageFileDialog.Title = "Select an image file";
                dlgopenImageFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
                dlgopenImageFileDialog.FileName = String.Empty;
                if (dlgopenImageFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    files = dlgopenImageFileDialog.FileNames;
                    if (files != null && files.Length > 0)
                    {
                        return "Multiple files selected";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return dlgopenImageFileDialog.FileName;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me in solving this performance issue.

Comment: There are no dbcalls in my application. The image processing part is slow Bitmap creation, saving, selecting active frame etc.

Comment: oh my bad. I misread it as you upgraded from Sql xxx to sql xxx

Comment: Did you ever find a reason for the performance downgrade or a solution? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Microsoft actually refactored their code implementation and they added extra hidden layers to their implementation that is causing the performance issue. This is in regards to their GDI library. They changed their implementation after win 2008 r2 server if i remember correctly